# How to concatenate characters in java?

Tags: java, character, concatenation

How do you concatenate characters in java? Concatenating strings would only require a `+` between the strings, but concatenating chars using `+` will change the value of the char into ascii and hence giving a numerical output. I want to do `System.out.println(char1+char2+char3...` and create a String word like this.

I could do

```
System.out.print(char1);
System.out.print(char2);
System.out.print(char3);
```

But, this will only get me the characters in 1 line. I need it as a string. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: See [other Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18217005/why-can-i-add-characters-to-strings-but-not-characters-to-characters) to learn WHY using '+' operator is unsuccessful ([favorite Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18217113/1357094) from there).

Answer (score 67):

Do you want to make a string out of them?

```
String s = new StringBuilder().append(char1).append(char2).append(char3).toString();
```

Note that

```
String b = "b";
String s = "a" + b + "c";
```

Actually compiles to

```
String s = new StringBuilder("a").append(b).append("c").toString();
```

**Edit**: as litb pointed out, you can also do this:

```
"" + char1 + char2 + char3;
```

That compiles to the following:

```
new StringBuilder().append("").append(c).append(c1).append(c2).toString();
```

**Edit (2)**: Corrected string append comparison since, as cletus points out, a series of strings is handled by the compiler.

The purpose of the above is to illustrate what the compiler does, not to tell you what you should do.

Comment: you are missing a toString() at the end of the first line of code.

Comment: You are incorrect.  "a" + "b" + "c" becomes "abc" at compile-time.  Its only evaluated at runtime if at least one of these operands can't be determined at compile-time.

Comment: @cletus I just checked and you're right about the "a" + "b" + "c".  The same thing happens with literal chars, but not when using variable references. Thanks for enlightening me.  :)

Comment: Does it create a `StringBuilder` or a `StringBuffer`?

Comment: Before StringBuilder existed, it used StringBuffer.

Comment: Since Java 9 Java does not use StringBuilder anymore for string concatenation like this.

Answer (score 27):

I wasn't going to answer this question but there are two answers here (that are getting voted up!) that are just plain wrong.  Consider these expressions:

```
String a = "a" + "b" + "c";
String b = System.getProperty("blah") + "b";
```

The first is evaluated at **compile-time**.  The second is evaluated at **run-time**.

So **never** replace constant concatenations (of any type) with StringBuilder, StringBuffer or the like.  Only use those where variables are invovled and generally only when you're appending a lot of operands or you're appending in a loop.

If the characters are constant, this is fine:

```
String s = "" + 'a' + 'b' + 'c';
```

If however they aren't, consider this:

```
String concat(char... chars) {
  if (chars.length == 0) {
    return "";
  }
  StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(chars.length);
  for (char c : chars) {
    s.append(c);
  }
  return s.toString();
}
```

as an appropriate solution.

However some might be tempted to optimise:

```
String s = "Name: '" + name + "'"; // String name;
```

into this:

```
String s = new StringBuilder().append("Name: ").append(name).append("'").toString();
```

While this is well-intentioned, the bottom line is **DON'T**.

Why?  As another answer correctly pointed out: the compiler does this for you.  So in doing it yourself, you're not allowing the compiler to optimise the code or not depending if its a good idea, the code is harder to read and its unnecessarily complicated.

**For low-level optimisation the compiler is better at optimising code than you are.**

Let the compiler do its job.  In this case the worst case scenario is that the compiler implicitly changes your code to exactly what you wrote.  Concatenating 2-3 Strings might be more efficient than constructing a StringBuilder so it might be better to leave it as is.  The compiler knows whats best in this regard.

Comment: indeed you are right. would be a bad design and silly if "a"+"b" created a stringbuilder. and i also agree that for only 1-5 concats, doing it with + is probably better than going into the hassle of creating a StringBuilder.

Comment: The compiler does that for you, but yes, in your last example, that is what the compiler outputs.  I completely agree that you *shouldn't* do that yourself, but I do think it's important to understand what happens.

Comment: I incorporated your suggestions into my answer.

Answer (score 13):

If you have a bunch of chars and want to concat them into a string, why not do

```
System.out.println("" + char1 + char2 + char3);
```

?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [String constructor](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(char[])).

```
System.out.println(new String(new char[]{a,b,c}));
```

Comment: Or java.nio.CharBuffer.wrap(new char[] { a, b, c }). :)

Comment: CharBuffer.wrap does not give String but CharBuffer, which implements CharSequence.

Comment: fwiw:  String also implements CharSequence (however, of course, this is not to imply that CharBuffer can be used directly as a String).

Answer (score 5):

You need to tell the compiler you want to do String concatenation by starting the sequence with a string, even an empty one. Like so:

```
System.out.println("" + char1 + char2 + char3...);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
System.out.println(char1+""+char2+char3)
```

or

```java
String s = char1+""+char2+char3;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a String object of some description to hold your array of concatenated chars, since the `char` type will hold only a single character. e.g.,

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder('a').append('b').append('c');
System.out.println(sb.toString);
```

Comment: Sorry but for constants this is bad advice.  The compiler optimises "" + 'a' + 'b' at compile time but cannot optimise your version so its a runtime expression.  If you're dealing with variable characters then this approach may have merit.

Answer (score 2):

public class initials {

```
public static void main (String [] args) {

    char initialA = 'M';
    char initialB = 'P';
    char initialC = 'T';

    System.out.println("" + initialA + initialB + initialC );


}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I don't really consider myself a Java programmer, but just thought I'd add it here "for completeness"; using the (C-inspired) `String.format` static method:

```
String s = String.format("%s%s", 'a', 'b'); // s is "ab"
```

Comment: And if it’s for printing, `System.out.format("%s%s", 'a', 'b')`.

Answer (score 1):

> this is very simple approach to concatenate or append the character

```
       StringBuilder desc = new StringBuilder(); 
       String Description="this is my land"; 
       desc=desc.append(Description.charAt(i));
```

Answer (score -1):

simple example to selecting character from string and appending to string variable

private static String findaccountnum(String holdername, String mobile) {

```
    char n1=holdername.charAt(0);
    char n2=holdername.charAt(1);
    char n3=holdername.charAt(2);
    char n4=mobile.charAt(0);
    char n5=mobile.charAt(1);
    char n6=mobile.charAt(2);
    String number=new StringBuilder().append(n1).append(n2).append(n3).append(n4).append(n5).append(n6).toString();

    return number;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
System.out.print(a + "" + b + "" + c);
```

Comment: please fix your code by indenting it with four spaces, and add a short explanation of how your answer works.