# String character concatenation

Tags: java, string, char, reverse

I was writing a piece of code to reverse a String wordwise(Input:Java is fun; Output:fun is Java), when I came across a question:How can a String variable be added to a character type variable.the code is working perfectly, but how is this possible? Someone, please explain this to me. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.io.*;
public class numberof {
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String str1,str2="",str3="";
str1=br.readLine()+" ";
for(int i=0;i<str1.length();i++){
char x=str1.charAt(i);
if(x==' '){
    str2=str3+" "+str2;
str3="";
}
else{
    str3=str3+x;   //HERE IS THE QUESTION PART(STRING+CHAR)

   }
 }
 System.out.println(str2);  
 }

  }
```

Comment: Implicit type conversion

Comment: [This guy][1] gives a pretty decent rundown of what's happening.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/328253/2400222

Comment: @Zec Pretty sure you can just put the link in like this: "\[link-name\](link-address)"

Comment: @whowantsakookie - Thanks. I actually submitted that as an answer but SO said it was "trivial" and made it a comment, making the link go whacky. Figured it's clickable and has value regardless. Leaving it as is out of spite. Trivial?!

Comment: @Zec I think you were right. That is a good answer and this question could have actually just been answered via a simple google search.

Comment: @Zec it's not trivial, but against the rules of SO. Refer to [What is an acceptable answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118582/182862), section 6.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - Thanks. I suspected my answer might not be sufficient to be called an answer, but it was to a question for which answers abound. Also, I couldn't think of a clever analogy like cans or necklaces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `char` can be implicitly converted into a `String`. If Java didn't do this, you would have had to write it as following:

```
str3 = str3 + String.valueOf(x);
```

Heck, even the `+` operator is overloaded for `String`s in Java. Without which, you would have had to write it like this:

```
str3 = str3.concat(String.valueOf(x));
```

So implicit type conversions make it easy for you to write code. And it's easy for you to read and understand the same code:

```
str3 = str3 + x;
//understanding: the string 'str3' is being joined with the character 'x'
```

Note, however that not everything can be implicitly converted. For example, this wouldn't work:

```
char y = str3 + x; //ERROR: cannot cast string to char!
```

Implicit conversion only works when a basic type can be converted to a more advanced type without data loss. Here, a `String` can be thought of as a string of characters (think of those [letter-bead bracelets](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_9h3PZyBxY74/TJg8-8Q7aXI/AAAAAAAADsQ/940JIJRv_Ck/s400/c.JPG)). So a `char` can be thought of as a string with just one character. So what the `+` operator does is to add this character to the end of the other string full of characters.

Answer (score 2):

When there is a conflict between the conversion between data types, the compiler always chooses the larger data type(in your case it is string). This is called implicit type conversion.
Say you have 2 cans 1 of 1ltr capacity and the other 2ltr. It is always safe to pour the contents of 1ltr can to the 2 ltr can.

Comment: @One vote for you !!! Now i am curious to know that what does capacity means in context of java .. ??

Comment: Size of data type is capacity.. Like int is 4 bytes, char is 1 byte

Comment: Is this concept is related to autoboxing and unboxing in java ?