# Why can I add characters to strings but not characters to characters?

Tags: java, string, char, addition, concatenation

So I wanted to add a character to a string, and in some cases wanted to double that characters then add it to a string (i.e. add to it itself first). I tried this as shown below.

```
char s = 'X'; 
String string = s + s;
```

This threw up an error, but I'd already added a single character to a string so I tried:

```
String string = "" + s + s;
```

Which worked. Why does the inclusion of a string in the summation cause it to work? Is adding a string property which can only be used by characters when they're converted to strings due to the presence of a string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to concatenate characters in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328249/how-to-concatenate-characters-in-java)

Comment: The error that it threw is probably the answer to your question ;)

Comment: A character can only be a length of 1. Java doesn't "know" you are going to assign this expression to a String.

Comment: Similar Question [How to concatenate characters in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328249/how-to-concatenate-characters-in-java) asks/answers HOW to construct a String from >1 char. This Question asks/answers WHY attempting to do so with '+' operator is unsuccessful; worth asking (duplicate flag therefore retracted, and +1 added here :)

Comment: Please clarify the final sentence of your Question - what does it mean?  @SahilMahajanMj do you know?

Comment: @K.Nicholas do you know ^?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because String + Char = String, similar to how an int + double = double.

Char + Char is int despite what the other answers tell you.

String s = 1; // compilation error due to mismatched types.

Your working code is (String+Char)+Char. If you had done this: String+(Char+Char) you would get a number in your string. Example:

```
System.out.println("" + ('x' + 'x')); // prints 240
System.out.println(("" + 'x') + 'x'); // prints xx - this is the same as leaving out the ( ).
```

Comment: Well, you meant `char` and not `Char`, but nice line about ints regardless :)

Comment: I actually wrote char/Character initially, but then I didn't want to keep it up so I deleted and went compromise. :) You're right though. Char isn't anything in Java.

Comment: So at this point, why keep "Char"?  Why not use one of {`char`, `Character`, 'char/Character'}?  I'm not sure why keeping "Char" is a better compromise?  I'd edit it myself, but want to make sure I'm not missing something...

Answer (score 4):

`char` + `char` returns an `int` so the compiler complains that `String string = (int)`, which is indeed wrong.

To concatenate the chars, you can use the empty String (`""`) at the beginning so the `+` operator will be for `String` concatenation **or** use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) that can append chars as well.

```
char s = 'X';
String string = new StringBuilder().append(s).append(s).toString();
```

Note: the `char` variable is `s`, not `X`.

Comment: @Pshemo `char`+`char`=`int`. Try this: `char a = 'a', b = 'b', c; c = a + b;`

Comment: +1 and to add some info: result of `char1` + `char2` is `int` that is sum of positions of `char1` and `char2` in [UnicodeTable](http://unicode-table.com/en/). So for `'X'+'X'` result will be `88 + 88` = `176` which if OP would like to cast to char would be `°`.

Answer (score 3):

In Java, `char` is a primitive integral numeric type. As such, the operator + is defined to mean *addition* of two chars, with an `int` result. The operator means concatenation only on strings. So one way to do it is

```
"" + char1 + char2
```

This will coerce the right-hand operand to a string, which is what you want to achieve.

A side point: `char` is the only unsigned primitive numeric type in Java and in one project of mine I specifically use it as such.

Comment: Thank you for the "_unsigned_ primitive numeric type" (emphasis "unsigned") side note - I didn't realize that before.

Answer (score 0):

When you do 
`char s = 'X'; String string = X + X;`

Why not do this instead?
`char s = 'X'; String string = s + s;`

Comment: I think OP was just sloppy while posting :p

Comment: I'm not a pro at java-- so I thought his solution might have been that simple : p

Answer (score 0):

Adding in the "" changes the return type to a string.  Leaving it out means the return type is a char which doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

String string = "" + X + X;

is an example of concatenation. By pre-pending the empty string you specify that the result should be a string. The first line of code tells the compiler that you are adding 2 chars (or ints) which should result in an int, and not a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
 String string = X + X;
```

Here X i'ts threated as a variable

You should use something as

```
String string ="x x";
```

Or

```
String x = "something";
String y = "else";
```

then `String string= x+y;`
should work just fine, this is because you are concatening with the "+" sign, you could also use

```
string = string.concat(x+y);
```

or

```
string = string.concat("something"+"else");
```