# Convert 2 chars to a string

Tags: java

I have 2 chars I need converting to a string. I can convert one no problem but how do I turn 2 randomly generated chars into one string? Here is my code so far, the aim of my program is to generate two chars at random and return them:

```
import java.util.Random;
public class PasswordGenerator {

    Random rand = new Random();

    public String uppercaseLetters() {
    char char1;
    char char2;
    String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    String result;


    char1 = alphabet.charAt(rand.nextInt(25));
    char2 = alphabet.charAt(rand.nextInt(25));


    result = String.valueOf(char1, char2);
    return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    PasswordGenerator pg = new PasswordGenerator();

    System.out.println(pg.uppercaseLetters());

    }

}
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328249/how-to-concatenate-characters-in-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to concatenate characters in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328249/how-to-concatenate-characters-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `String` concatenated with a `char` is a `String`<sup>1</sup>. So you could do,

```
result = String.valueOf(char1) + char2;
```

**or** something like

```
result = "" + char1 + char2;
```

Also, I'd really prefer to use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). I'd also make the `length` an *argument*, move the `Random` and `String` out of the method.

```
class PasswordGenerator {
    final Random rand = new Random();
    final static String upperCase = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    public String uppercaseLetters(int len) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            sb.append(upperCase.charAt(rand.nextInt(upperCase.length())));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Then you could call it like `pg.uppercaseLetters(2)` or `pg.uppercaseLetters(4)` and get `n` letters (instead of `2`).

<sup>1<sub>`char` is an [*integral value*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1) in Java, so `char`+`char` is an `int`.</sub></sup>

Comment: Thank you, could you please explain what the double quotes are for? Why does the code not work without them?

Comment: @JamesB The **empty string** (`""`) makes it `String + char + char` which is `String`, `char + char` is an `int` (because `char` is an integral type, and `'a' + 1 == 'b'`)

Comment: The superscript <sup>1<sup> tag does not explain the 1st sentence of this Answer that is tagged with that.  Please edit to clarify that confusing disconnect.

Answer (score 3):

One of String's constructors takes a `char[]`, so that lets you construct the String straightforwardly, without concatenation tricks or StringBuilder.

```
result = new String(new char[] { char1, char2 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html),

```
public String uppercaseLetters() {
        char char1;
        char char2;
        String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        String result;

        char1 = alphabet.charAt(rand.nextInt(25));
        char2 = alphabet.charAt(rand.nextInt(25));

        result = new StringBuilder().append(char1).append(char2).toString();

        return result;
    }
```

or just `return new StringBuilder().append(char1).append(char2).toString();`

Answer (score 0):

Change one line:

```
result = "" + char1 + char2;
```

Also, you don't need to create variable `result`, you can simply do:

```
return = "" + char1 + char2;
```