# How do I fix an <identifier> expected error on line 89 when using cases?

Tags: java, string, methods, identify

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MethodTestingLab {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      int menuChoice, num1;
      Scanner keyboardReader = new Scanner(System.in);

      // Display Menu
      System.out.println("Menu\n 1.chkNextInt\n 2.twoDigitNumber\n 3.big2Digits\n 4.reverseString\n 5.max3\n");

      // User choice
      System.out.print("Enter your choice ");
      menuChoice = keyboardReader.nextInt();


      // Cases
      switch(menuChoice) {
         case 4:
            System.out.println("Given a three-lettered string, returns the string that is the reverse of its characters.");
            System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
            case4String = keyboardReader.next();
            System.out.println(reverseString(case4String));
            break;
      }
      System.out.println("End");
   }


   // Method 4
   public static String reverseString(case4String) {
      newString = case4String.charAt(2) + case4String.charAt(1) + case4String.charAt(0);
      return newString;
   }

}
```

// How do I fix the identify error in Method 4? I can't compile it until it is fixed, and when I tried adding String before case4String, it caused way more errors than the one before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569335/reverse-a-string-in-java)

Comment: Also, possibly [How to concatenate characters in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328249/how-to-concatenate-characters-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are just learning Java, congratulations! ccKep was right that you are missing several identifiers. To define a variable in Java, you have to tell the compiler what type the variable is going to hold. The same way you defined `menuChoice` and `num1` as the type `int`, you have to do the same for the variable `case4String` and `newString`.

Another issue is that you cannot concatenate the `char` type with the `+` operator in your `reverseString` method. There are a couple ways to fix that. One way you can get a `String` from `char` type is to create a new `String` from a `char` array.

```
// Method 4
static String reverseString(String case4String) {
    char[] chars = {case4String.charAt(2), case4String.charAt(1), case4String.charAt(0)};
    String newString = new String(chars); // and here.
    return newString;
}
```

Or you can use one of the suggestions from the [Reverse a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569335/reverse-a-string-in-java) answer provided by ccKep.

```
// Method 4
static String reverseString(String case4String) {
    StringBuilder newStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(case4String); // and here.
    return newStringBuilder.reverse().toString();
}
```

This is a better answer because it does not limit you to the three character limit, the way you have to do it with your `charAt` solution. Here's the code with the identifiers fixed and the second proposed solution.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MethodTestingLab {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int menuChoice, num1;
        Scanner keyboardReader = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Display Menu
        System.out.println("Menu\n 1.chkNextInt\n 2.twoDigitNumber\n 3.big2Digits\n 4.reverseString\n 5.max3\n");

        // User choice
        System.out.print("Enter your choice ");
        menuChoice = keyboardReader.nextInt();


        // Cases
        switch(menuChoice) {
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Given a three-lettered string, returns the string that is the reverse of its characters.");
                System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
                String case4String = keyboardReader.next();
                System.out.println(reverseString(case4String));
                break;
        }
        System.out.println("End");
    }


    // Method 4
    public static String reverseString(String case4String) {
        StringBuilder newStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(case4String); // and here.
        return newStringBuilder.reverse().toString();
    }

}
```