# Issue in Java related output

Tags: java

I ran the below code on my computer:

```
char ch = 'E';
System.out.print(ch + ++ch);
```

I expected `EF` but the output was `139`.
Why is the ASCII value added and printed.

My question is why is the output is `139` not `EF`?

Comment: Adding two `char` values in Java returns an `int`.  If you did `System.out.print(ch + "" + ++ch);` instead, the result would be `EF`. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688668/in-java-is-the-result-of-the-addition-of-two-chars-an-int-or-a-char).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Java, is the result of the addition of two chars an int or a char?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688668/in-java-is-the-result-of-the-addition-of-two-chars-an-int-or-a-char) or [How to concatenate characters in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328249/how-to-concatenate-characters-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

As @Nexevis already stated, adding 2 chars giving you an integer. ([Here is why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688668/in-java-is-the-result-of-the-addition-of-two-chars-an-int-or-a-char))

However, to solve your problem use `String.valueOf(obj)`

```
System.out.print(String.valueOf(ch) + String.valueOf(++ch));
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the way Java stores `char` variables.

In Java, `char` is stored like an `int` and therefore the numeric values of your characters are added when you do `ch + ++ch`.

> A char always holds it's ascii / unicode **numeric** value.

Answer (score 1):

`+` operator in Java is a Arithmetic operator so it is treated both `char` values with there Arithmetic value of char `E` i.e. 69

c+ ++c ==> 69 + 70 = 139

if you need to add two char as like concatenation of string you can do it like follows :

```
        char ch ='E';
        System.out.print(ch+""+ (++ch));
```

Comment: @Subrat Singh Is your query resolved ? Can you please accept my answer it you got the answer for your question